# openstack instance's image name lost after integration with ceph rbd

Tags: openstack, ceph

after integrated with ceph rbd,my openstack could not show "image name" of my instance, is there any option that controlling this feature?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like you made changes to Glace or the template you were using was local but now it is referring to ceph for template. Do you see the image in "openstack image list" ?